# GraphQL resolve multiple schema dynamically

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, java-8, schema, graphql

I'm developing a graphql service using [com.graphql-java:graphql-java:8.0] dependencies. Basically, I need to fetch some conditional data based on parent schema response. e.g, If ResultOne response contentTypeId == 1 for which, I need to fetch and prepare additional response using Fish type schema, accordingly for contentTypeId == 2, I need to fetch and prepare response using Fruit type schema.

```
extend type Query {
    search(
        name: String,
        category: String
    ): [ResultOne]
}

type ResultOne {
    contentTypeId: Int
    content: Content
}

type Fish {
    name: String    
    weight: Float
}

type Fruit {
    name: String
    Color: String
}

type Toy {
    name: String
    description: String
}
```

I have tired with union but in that case, an exception occurred "There is no type resolver defined for interface/union 'Content' type".

```
union Content = Fish | Fruit |Toy
```

Please, feel free to ask me your question, If my problem not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with Unions - you are close and the error is quite helpful - "There is no type resolver defined for interface/union 'Content' type" - meaning that you have to write that Content resolver, that will match correct type to contentTypeId. I can't help you here, as I write my GrapQL APIs with Node.js.

But I would suggest using Interface here. If you have a Searchable interface, you can easily write such schema:

```
extend type Query {
    search(
        name: String,
        category: String
    ): [Searchable]
}

interface Searchable {
    contentTypeId: Int
    name: String
}

type Fish implements Searchable {
    contentTypeId: Int
    name: String    
    weight: Float
}

type Fruit implements Searchable {
    contentTypeId: Int
    name: String
    Color: String
}

type Toy implements Searchable {
    contentTypeId: Int
    name: String
    description: String
}
```

Here is a nice explanation on when to use Interfaces and Unions:

https://medium.com/the-graphqlhub/graphql-tour-interfaces-and-unions-7dd5be35de0d